# Please explain an iteration function in this for statement

Tags: loops, for-loop, sum, iteration

This is a pretty simple for loop I have come across in a Java tutorial by Schildt. I have been studying it for some time now and am still unsure of how it returns the value 15. In particular I can't figure out the role played by the "sum" variable in the iteration protion of the statement. A good explanation of this would greatly help me in moving forward in my study of java. The author of the book simply throws this out there as an example of how to use a loop without a body with no explanation of the "sum" value and how it is iterated.

Here is the statement:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 5; sum += i++)   
    System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
```

How do we explain the variable sum as having the final value of 15 in this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what will happen inside the loop.

1. i=1; sum = 1;

   i=2; sum = 1+2 = 3;

   i=3; sum = 3+3 = 6;

   i=4; sum = 6+4 = 10;

   i=5; sum = 10+5 = 15;

Answer (score 0):

`i` increases 5 times due to the `i++` statement, and is added to `sum` in each loop iteration, so

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

This instruction does two things : `sum += i++`

first:

```
sum = sum + i;
```

and later:

`i = i + 1;`

//Initial values

```
sum = 0;
i = 1;
```

//When the loop finish its last instruction in this case the print

```
sum = sum + 1
sum = 1;
i = i + 1;
i = 2;
```

============

```
sum = sum + 2
sum = 3;
i = i + 1;
i = 3;
```

============

```
sum = sum + 3
sum = 6;
i = i + 1;
i = 4;
```

============

```
sum = sum + 4
sum = 10;
i = i + 1;
i = 5;
```

============

```
sum = sum + 5
sum = 15;
i = i + 1;
i = 6;
```

Comment: I think the issue with this explanation is that i is assigned the value of 6 in your final iteration; this is a condition prohibited by the expression "i <= 5" in the loop. How do we avoid that?

Comment: The explanation is correct, the computer assign i = 6; then asks  6<=5 this is false so the loops is over..